# Benefits of having multiple Web.Config files in ASP.NET Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

We can have multiple web.config files in asp.net application.

What are the advantages of having multiple web.config files?

Please any one give a better solution for this question..

Comment: I have narrowed my question. Please give suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

web.confing apply it's settings to all application if it is at root and only one web.config is present. but suppose there is one additional web.config in any particular folder then it's settings will affect only that particular folder and subfolders of that folder. Files on root folder will refer only web.config at root.

Comment: In which situations we can go for another web.config to a sub folder?

Comment: It gives only the partial answer for this question.

Comment: Real life situation is MVC folder structure @thevan